# check on last section element

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can check on the last section element. I have a lot of sections on the page. I want check on the last. I have this

```
if ($("section:last")) {
Button.hide();
} else {
Button.animate():
}
```

But this is not working...

Comment: Show some of your html also. What do you want to do?

Comment: What do you mean by section, the html5 tag ? If it's the case, what do you want to get in this tag? Because it's usually containing alot of elements. Thx

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I change the post. I have a carousel with 5 sections. When.the last section is show. He must hide the button.

Comment: Your question does not make sense... what is the context of this code? When are you making the check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your function need to go through all sections and you need to know if you're at the last section, you can put all sections in `class="section"` and try this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var len = $('.section').length;
    $('.section').each(function(index, element) {
        if (index == len - 1) {
          // This is the last element, do what you need to do with it here
        } else {
          // This is not the last element, do something else
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to do something only to the last element that satisfies a criteria then:

```
  $(".section:last").css("background-color", "red");
```

would set it red. You do not need the if statement for this.